how to make this table in latex
Could anyone tell me how to make this table in latex?
thank you so much.


I'd not do a table like this even if paid for it.

You should show what you tried so far as it is much easier to help you with concrete problems based on your code. There are lots of examples on this site and on the internet that can serve as starting points. This site is not meant to be a free human-powered image-to-TeX conversion tool

Is all the extra whitespace in the lower areas of the cells really required? Is there a chance that this table will need to span two or more pages, i.e., that it won't fit on a single page? Please advise.

No @Mico Thanks a lot

I suggest you employ a tabularx environment, set its target width to \textwidth, and allow automatic line breaking in columns 2 thru 9.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{fontspec} % optional (requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX)
\setmainfont{Calibri} % optional (use a "condensed" font face)

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % left alignment
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}   % centering

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped "look"
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\footnotesize

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|*{8}{L|}}
\hline
Reference & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Design} 
          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Implementation}
          & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Experiment} \\
\hline
& Objective & Approach & Limitations\slash Challenges
& Tools\slash Framework & Security
& Dataset & KPI & Results \\
\hline\hline
VL2 [2020] & Image classification & APSI+ AVLR 
& Imbalanced\slash Asymmetric Feature Dist & FATE, Tencent Cloud 
& SMC Asymmetrical PSI & MNIST & Area under curve (AUC), Loss 
& Validates the feasibility of the APSI + AVLR with 
  as good performance as its symmetrical version \\
\hline
VL2 [2020] & Binary classification & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I would recommend using https://www.tablesgenerator.com. You can create this very same table using "known Excel commands". There, you can merge/split cells, and then you might want to get a LaTeX code that generates the table for you.
Remember to use some packages when needed.

The LaTeX code generated by tablegenerators.com tends to be grossly inefficient and convoluted. As a result, it's extremely tedious -- even for seasoned LaTeX table specialists -- to hand-edit the code to apply any further changes. Once a beginner-level user goes down the tablegenerators.com rabbit hole, they'll likely be stuck forever with this inefficient and virtually unmaintainable method. Put differently, while it may be (barely) ok to employ tablegenerators.com for one-off uses, it's not a good idea to rely on it. Do make an effort to learn how to code tables in LaTeX yourself.

I don't use tablesgenerator.com in my routine. But I truly believe that a lot of effort is needed for beginners to get used to code tables themselves and, perhaps, can make them give up on learning it. My "hint" here was to solve a "one-off" use, as I think you're right on that.
